# Confused about QT Creator Programming app (Different versions)

Tags: windows, android, osx, ios

I am really confused about the different "versions" of QT Creator. My target of using QT is to develop apps for Mac, Windows, Android and iOS. I don't understand the difference between these 4 separate apps. 
[image: Different app "versions" available on QT website]

I downloaded all of them and installed on different folders, I found that they make no difference on the user interface and the about window of the app.

[image: I installed all "versions" of QT app with different folders]

[image]

At last, can anyone tell me what's the difference and which one should I choose if I want to develop Mac, Windows, Android and iOS apps in a single app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing QT Creator with QT SDK.

**QT Creator** is the IDE code editor - download the version for the OS you are writing code in.

**QT SDK** - you can have

- one for the OS you are currently developing on (must have)
- others for mobile development

If you target multiple platforms, the best way is to use the online installer and select what you want.

In your case:

- QT for Mac
- QT for Android
- QT for iOS

If you want to build Windows apps, you'll have to install the SDK on a Windows PC, obviously the Windows version of it.

Here is what you should choose if running Windows and also want mobile platforms:

[image]

What I selected and why:

- MinGW 4.8 - that are the SDK binaries for Windows and libraries for MinGW compiler - needed for Windows development
- Android arm v7 - SDK prebuilt binaries for Android development
- MinGW 4.8 - I want to install the MinGW compiler because I don't have Visual C++ (if I had used VC++ I would have chosen the SDK for it!)
- QT Creator is auto selected.

In the Mac version you will have slightly different options.

Comment: Hello! I was trying to use the online installer, but because I am living far away from their servers, the online installer never success on downloading the components. Any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: @user294928 well you can use every SDK for its target. It will take more HDD space. I don't know if it is possible to merge multiple SDKs in one installation.

Comment: It's fine that it's separated to different installations, but can I develop apps from a single app then export it with other SDKs.

Comment: @user294928 the same project (source code) you can import in any SDK.

Comment: Thanks! It should work like the normal online installer.